# Change increase of variable during computation - python

Tags: python, variables, computation

My simulation  has a similar structure as:

```
T  = 10   # Number of time steps
dt = 1     # time increment

t_points = []

for i in range(T+1) :

    t = i * dt
    t_points.append(t)               

     for j in range(100) :  

         ''                            # do some computation that depends on t
```

I want now to change the increment size dt from 1 to 0.1 when t is equal to 5 and keep that size afterwards. This should lead to the following output:

```
--> t_points = [0,1,2,3,4,5,5.1,5.2,.....]
```

Currently im using two seperate computations, one with dt = 1 and dt = 0.01. In the end i combine the results.

Is there an other convenient way to do this?

Comment: your question is not clear enough. please rephrase

Comment: what is your issue? you seem to have found the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, appending two separately computed lists sounds perfectly sensible to me.

However, you could also do:

```
T  = 10   # Number of time steps
dt = 1     # time increment

t_points = []

for i in range(T+1) :

    t = i * dt
    t_points.append(t)               

    for j in range(100):
         pass  # do some computation that depends on t

    if t >= 5:
        dt = 0.1
```

The precise placing of the conditional may need to vary depending on what happens in your elided computations.